# Difference between JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 2015 and JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

What is the difference between JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 2015 and JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance? Why to choose one over other?

Answer (score 2):

They function almost exactly the same.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 2015 are *primarily syntactical sugar* over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript.

ES2015 `class`es are simply an easier way to write JavaScript's traditional prototype-based inheritance.

Some people feel that `class` isn't a good idea since JS doesn't have classes in the traditional sense. However, there's no denying that `class` makes your code much shorter when compared to using the traditional `prototype` method.

One small difference to note: `function`s are hoisted. `class`es are not. For example:

```
let p = new Rectangle(); // ReferenceError

class Rectangle {}
```